# Is it safe to use different git versions for origin and local repos?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I would like to start using magit to manage my local git repo. when I try to run magit (magit-status) it complains:

"Error (magit): Magit requires Git >= 2.0.0, you are using 1.8.3."

Can I upgrade the local version of git from 1.8.3 to the latest version and still interact safely with the origin repo? or will the origin also have to be upgraded?

Comment: Your version of git is at least 7 years old. Indeed, you should think about upgrading it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was if origin and local repos can have different git versions.  Let's start there.

Yes, though there is no git version "for origin" as origin (normally) runs on a remote repo, say GitLab.  Of course, "origin" could be your machine in which case both versions are these.

The error you see is different. Here, "magit" (which I also use and love) in installed in a version that requires a new "git" (i.e. the local binary on your computer) than you have.  So do run *that version of `magit`* on your computer you need to *upgrade your versions of `git`*.  "origin" has nothing to do with.

What OS / version are you running and how easy would that be?

Comment: Centos 7, magit 2.90.1, git 1.8.3.1, emacs 27.1. If I understand you correctly, I have two options here. I could install the version of magit that works with git 1.8* or I can just upgrade my local version of git. If upgrading the local version of git is unlikely to trash the origin repo then I will give that a go. thanks for the quick response,

Comment: Yes, I was in a similar sitation a while back and just compiled a local `git` binary and stuck it into `~/bin`.  If you are on good terms with your sysadmin he can probably get you a newer `git` from from the EPEL repos.  And for your initial concern: no, there is no way this will affect your repositories.  You can run on them with a newer binary, your colleagues may have an older one _but a) the wire protocol did not change and b) you both to the same server who will accomodate all `git` binaries_.

Comment: The Git developers care a great deal about backwards-compatibility, so the chances of experiencing a problem are very slim. For full details I think you would need to track back through the release notes, though.  Any compatibility matters are always highlighted (but in the *vast* majority of cases are not going to be of practical concern).  The most recent release with a BC note is: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.28.0.txt so you could work back from there if you wanted to know everything.

Comment: I don't use magit myself so it's possible that the magit authors paper over some of the issues in Git1.x (when using an older magit, of course!) ... but it's worth noting that there are a lot of annoying things in 1.x fixed in 2.x, if you do ever use the command line.

Comment: OP: I have successfully upgraded my local git installation (1.8.3.1 -> 2.18) using the git package on offer from [softwarecollections.org](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-git218/). Thanks @Dirk Eddelbuettel for your original response and to others who 'chipped in'. Also thanks to leoluk for suggesting this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/709433/install-a-newer-version-of-git-on-centos-7) and l3g3nd4ryf0x  for details on how to make switch between git installations eazy peazy! [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/751155/permanently-enable-a-scl)